# QHostInfo issue

Tags: c++, qt, dns, ip

i want a method to get a QStringList of IPs associated to an URL, i have those tow methods and they work perfectly but i want all of this is on single method like this: `QStringList DNSResolver(QString host);`

```
 void Object::test()

{
    QHostInfo::lookupHost("www.google.com",this, SLOT(lookedUp(QHostInfo)));
}

void Object::lookedUp(const QHostInfo &host)
{

    if (host.error() != QHostInfo::NoError) {
        qDebug() << "Lookup failed:" << host.errorString();
    }

    foreach (const QHostAddress &address, host.addresses())
    {
         qDebug() << "Lookup success:" << address.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `QHostInfo::fromName ( const QString & name )` which blocks during the lookup :

```
QStringList DNSResolver(QString host)
{
    QHostInfo hostInfo; 
    QHostInfo returnedHost = hostInfo.fromName(host);

    if (returnedHost.error() != QHostInfo::NoError) {
         qDebug() << "Lookup failed:" << returnedHost.errorString();
    }

    QStringList list;
    foreach (const QHostAddress &address, returnedHost.addresses())
    {
          list<<address.toString();
    }

    return list;

}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Nejat, you have just to change the name of the QString  passed as parameters to DNSResolver because it conflicts with the QHostInfo.
Besides the solution works perfectly :D thanks again.